# How to create kernel and user stack in window

Tags: multithreading, window, kernel

How do I create both kernel and user thread in window?

I believed CreateThread is under kernel thread basic on its DLL?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

If there is the case how do I create a user thread?

Answer (score 0):

I don`t clearly understand what you want. There are several threading functions

1) PsCreateSystemThread - only km drivers can use this. Thread executes in system context with only km stack.

2) CreateThread - usermode api, call to undocument system service NtCreateThread, have both km and um stacks and executes in current process context.

3) Fibers (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682661(v=vs.85).aspx) - totally usermode execution units, they must be scheduled manually. Many fibers executes within one real thread.

4) UMS (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd627187(v=vs.85).aspx) some middle between fibers and real thread. I don't work with it and can`t say more.